# How to figure out what device (if any) my DVD drive is assigned to in Debian GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, debian, dvd, gnu

I am running stock Debian Jessie and I would like to burn a DVD with xfburn. Problem is that xfburn can't see my DVD drive. e.g. it does not show up under as /dev/scd0 or any other (as far as I can tell).

My DVD drive is a IDE drive who is connected via a IDE/SATA adapter to a internal SATA port. The DVD drive is set to master as stated by the adapters documentation and the adapter is configured correctly.

dmesg | grep NEC does find my dvd drive and it shows up like this:

ata5.00: ATAPI: _NEC DVD_RW ND-3520AW, 2.U5, max UDMA/33

So I am basically pondering: Where do I go from here?!

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, The main intention is to learn "where the chain is broken". I can get the DVD drive to work if I configure the SATA controller for legacy IDE "emulation" it just does not work under AHCI that's all. I replaced the drive with a newer sata version however I would still like how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Have you tried `lsusb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  sudo lshw -businfo
```

It should appear there. For instance, in my case, I obtain:

```
  lshw -businfo

  Bus info    Device      Class          Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  ========================================================                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                          system         PORTEGE R930 (PT331E)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                          bus            PORTEGE R930                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                          memory         128KiB BIOS                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                          memory         6GiB System Memory                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                          memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)                                                                                                                                                                                    
                          memory         2GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)                                                                                                                                                                                    
 cpu@0                    processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz                                                                                                                                                                                          
                          memory         32KiB L1 cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                          memory         256KiB L2 cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                          memory         4MiB L3 cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                          memory         32KiB L1 cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
pci@0000:00:00.0              bridge         3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller                                                                                                                                                                                            
pci@0000:00:02.0              display        3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller                                                                                                                                                                                        
pci@0000:00:14.0              bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller                                                                                                                                                                      
pci@0000:00:16.0              communication  7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1                                                                                                                                                                             
pci@0000:00:16.3              communication  7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller                                                                                                                                                                                 
pci@0000:00:19.0  eth0        network        82579LM Gigabit Network Connection                                                                                                                                                                                                
pci@0000:00:1a.0              bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2                                                                                                                                                               
pci@0000:00:1b.0              multimedia     7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller                                                                                                                                                              
pci@0000:00:1c.0              bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1                                                                                                                                                                       
pci@0000:01:00.0              generic        MMC/SD Host Controller                                                                                                                                                                                                            
pci@0000:00:1c.1              bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2                                                                                                                                                                       
pci@0000:00:1c.2              bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express     Root Port 3                                                                                                                                                                       
pci@0000:04:00.0  wlan0       network        Centrino Advanced-N 6235                                                                                                                                                                                                          
pci@0000:00:1c.5              bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6                                                                                                                                                                       
pci@0000:00:1d.0              bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1                                                                                                                                                               
pci@0000:00:1f.0              bridge         QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller                                                                                                                                                                                               
pci@0000:00:1f.2              storage        7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]                                                                                                                                                                        
              scsi0       storage        
scsi@0:0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk           256GB TOSHIBA THNSNF25
scsi@0:0.0.0,1    /dev/sda1   volume         27GiB EXT4 volume
scsi@0:0.0.0,2    /dev/sda2   volume         210GiB Extended partition
              /dev/sda5   volume         5722MiB Linux swap / Solaris partition
              /dev/sda6   volume         204GiB Linux filesystem partition
              scsi2       storage        
scsi@2:0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD-RAM UJ8C2
                          power          Lithium Ion Battery
                          power          
              wwan0       network        Ethernet interface
```

You see it toward the end. Alternatively, you can use:

```
  lshw -C disk
  *-disk                  
   description: ATA Disk
   product: TOSHIBA THNSNF25
   vendor: Toshiba
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: FSTA
   serial: Y2ES102UT5MY
   size: 238GiB (256GB)
   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
   configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=0db170df
   *-cdrom
   description: DVD-RAM writer
   product: DVD-RAM UJ8C2
   vendor: MATSHITA
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   version: 1.00
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
   configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

which again shows the presence of the cd-rom reader.

Edit:

Before saying that your DVD reader does not work, you should know that a SATA interface can be used with two different protocols, IDE and AHCI. Go to your BIOs and check whether you can change mode to the other one, since the one you have clearly does not work.

Now try lshw again. If it does not appear once again, then it is broken.

Comment: I tried lshw but my dvd does not appear at all in the listing.

Comment: @Waxhead Please see the edit to my post.

Comment: I can get the drive to work if configured as IDE in the BIOS. However since the system can see the hardware I would like to learn how I can make it register properly and use it without IDE "emulation".

Comment: @Waxhead No you should not. See here: http://forum-en.msi.com/faq/article/ide-sata-and-ahci-all-you-need-to-know, you can read: *In your BIOS, your SATA controller has selectable modes of operation. Typically these are:
IDE - In this context, it simply means to use 'legacy' ATA operation mode. It can also be referred to as 'IDE emulation', which itself is misleading, as explained earlier, all SATA drives are themselves IDE devices. For using multiple independent drives, this mode of operation can be selected. Note there is no performance 'loss' using this.*

Comment: I am in fact aware of this. I would not like to 'sacrifice' ncq and the main purpose for me posting this is to learn how to get it running under ahci.

Comment: @Waxhead It was not hen you posted the first time. You should now update your post.

Answer (score 0):

The following command may be useful:

```
$> ls /sys/block/

fd0/ sda/ sr0/
```

As you can see in the output from my system, fd0 is the floppy drive, sda is the hard drive (you can see it in the dmesg command output). sr0 is my DVD drive (as it's the only other block device present in the PC).

I tested this on a Debian Squeeze, but I think should work the same on Jessie.

Comment: I can not see my dvd drive. However I can see my raid arrays, drives and so on.

Comment: So my guess is that your system can't handle your DVD drive. See the answer from @MariusMatutiae, which gives more suggestions you might find useful.